# c# group by doesn't work

Tags: c#, group-by

i have some problems with my c# code everywhere in the Examples they do it like me but somehow i gonna get some errors

Compiler says at g.Datum  he doesn' t know Datum

and at "return query" he says - `cannot convert`, there is a explicit convert

```
     var query = (from p in dataContext.Untersuchungen
                  orderby p.Datum
                  group p by p.Datum into g 
                  let number = (from n in dataContext.Untersuchungen
                                where n.Datum == g.Datum
                                select n).Count()
                  select new StatsistikObjekt() { Date1 = g.Datum, number1 = number });
       return query;
```

hope you can help me =)

Comment: Very interesting; I never knew you could even use `let` in a linq query. Almost looked like a mix of C# and F# =D

Comment: g.Datum should be g.Key, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

The type of the range variable `g` is the *group*, which indeed doesn't have a `Datum` value.

You can fix that bit easily, given your grouping (which uses `Datum` as the key)- and make your query simpler too by just counting the size of the group:

```
var query = (from p in dataContext.Untersuchungen
             orderby p.Datum
             group p by p.Datum into g
             select new StatsistikObjekt() { Date1 = g.Key,
                                             number1 = g.Count() });
```

As for the return value - we can't really help you on that one, as we don't know the return type you're trying to return.

Comment: I get half way through writing my answer and realize I've been one-upped by the great Jon Skeet. One day, good sir, one day.

Comment: @Tim: Just write you own answer and compare it with Jon's super-awesome super-fast answer after the fact.  Practice makes perfect.  You won't get better in a daze.  Besides, someone might like your answer.

Comment: @Tim I call it getting "skeet'd". Keep trying. You could get lucky and end up with something like this http://i.imgur.com/GLcaM.png . Current score; me: 1 Skeet: 2000+

Answer (score 1):

Try

`g.Key` instead of  `g.Datum`